# Show UIPickerView on Gesture Tapped

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uipickerview

My current app works when I tapped a text field, it would bring up the `UIPickerView`, but what if I tapped an image itself (gesture is placed over the image)?

```
class SomeVC: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {
  @IBOutlet weak var inputLabel: UITextField!
  @IBOutlet weak var laImageGestureTapped: UITapGestureRecognizer!

  let demoPicker = UIPickerView()

  // viewDidLoad()
  inputLabel.inputView = demoPicker // All is well with this.

  // How to open the UIPickerView with laImageGestureTapped?

  // I have omitted the required functions for: numberOfRowsInComponent, viewForRow, didSelectRow, numberOfComponents etc
}
```

Am I [searching with the correct words](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=gesture%20tap%20to%20open%20uipicker%20view&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=eNB4WKreD8Sq8weEi5X4DA#q=gesture%20tap%20to%20open%20uipickerview&start=20)?

All I want is to show the picker when the image is tapped. Im not worried about `didSelectRow` as there will be an hidden label to do x, y and z.

If this question was already asked and answered, please to direct me. Thanks.

Comment: Rather than having a gestureRecognizer attached to a UIImageView, why not just have a button with an image?

Comment: @toddg A button placed over the image? That could work but I havent done it that way before. Let me see...

Comment: Yes, that would work. Or you could just use a button and set the button image.

Comment: Just using a button and setting the background image will be much easier.

Comment: All you need to make sure for a UIImageView is to set .isUserInteractiveEnabled to true. Unlike most other UIView subclasses, this one is defaulted to false.

Comment: Yes! That worked. What also worked lol is to move the textfield over the image and set it to clear (lazy way I know) thanks all.

Comment: @dfd [see this gist](https://gist.github.com/dfrib/52636d9fc34ad1d14302442548a38dda) where I explain the issue you asked about. The key thing here is to differ for the equality testing operator `==` and the **assignment** operator `=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an alternative method to putting a clear textfield over your image:

1. Create a button that has your image assigned to its background image property
2. Initialize your pickerView with its frame off of the screen
3. Create a IBAction for your button that calls the pickerView onto the screen and creates a tap gesture and adds that your view
4. Create the method that the tap gesture will call when fired, which will send your pickerView back off of the screen

Here is the relevant code:

```
class VC: UIViewController {
    var pickerView = UIPickerView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    ...
        pickerView = UIPickerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.bounds.height, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: 100)) //Step 2

    }

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton){ //Step 3

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            self.pickerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.bounds.size.height - self.pickerView.bounds.size.height, width: self.pickerView.bounds.size.width, height: self.pickerView.bounds.size.height)
    })
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(doneWithPickerView))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

    }

    func doneWithPickerView() { //Step 4

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            self.pickerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.bounds.size.height, width: self.pickerView.bounds.size.width, height: self.pickerView.bounds.size.height)
        })
    }
}
```

I think it's better practice in general to not use invisible views as they can caused trouble for your later on. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Sylar no problem :)